# Resource server test fails with Auth0 issuer uri

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, auth0

I created a simple example, only acts *Resource server* to provide APIs for clients.

The complete codes can be found on [Github - hantsy/spring-webmvc-auth0-sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-webmvc-auth0-sample).

I have browsed [Spring security samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/hello-security/src/main/resources), it used a `jwk-set-uri`, in my application, I used `issuer-uri` instead.

```yaml
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: <auth0 provided issuer uri>
```

And I followed [Auth0 Spring security 5 API Guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5) , add audience claim validation.

I tried to add a [ApplicationTests](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-webmvc-auth0-sample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/demo/ApplicationTests.java) using MockMVC.

```java
    @Test
    public void testGetById() throws Exception {
        Post post = Post.builder().title("test").content("test content").build();
        post.setId(1L);
        given(this.posts.findById(anyLong())).willReturn(Optional.of(post));

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(
                        get("/posts/{id}", 1L)
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("test"));

        verify(this.posts, times(1)).findById(any(Long.class));
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(this.posts);
    }
```

And my security config is similar to this.

```java
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain springWebFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(c -> c.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeRequests(c -> c
                        .antMatchers("/", "/info").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/posts/**").permitAll()//.hasAuthority("SCOPE_read:posts")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/posts/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_write:posts")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/posts/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_write:posts")
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/posts/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_delete:posts")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
                .cors().and().build();
    }
```

When running the tests.

```sh
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.test.web.servlet.DefaultMvcResult.setHandler(Object)" because "mvcResult" is null

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
```

I am not sure where is wrong? I have checked the official samples, it includes a [spring.factories file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/master/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/hello-security/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories) to enable a mockserver env, it is requried in the Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be the inclusion of `cors()` in the configuration.

Spring Security's `CorsFilter` delegates by default to `HandlerMappingInterceptor`, which wraps the request in a specialized `HttpServletRequestWrapper`. When combined with `RouterFunction`s, `MockMvc`'s `MVC_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE` request attribute is getting removed.

One fix, then, is to remove `cors()` from your configuration. Indeed, when I remove it from your sample, the tests run as expected.

Another is to not use the `HandlerMappingInterceptor` default. Instead, you can publish your own `CorsConfigurationSource`, like so:

```java
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();    
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

In your sample app, when I added the above to your `SecurityConfig`, the tests ran again as expected.

It seems like there might be a way to adjust this specialized wrapper in `HandlerMappingIntrospector` as well so as to not accidentally remove the `MVC_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE`, but [the Spring Framework team](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues) will probably have more to say if any adjustments are needed. I've filed [a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26833) there to see if anything can be done.